# If $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-x+2$ ,Find an expression for the function $y$, which is obtained by rotating the graph of $f (x)$ through $180°$.

Tags: graphing-functions, rotations, cubics

> > Question: $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-x+2$  where $x\leq 1$
> >
> > Find an expression for the function $y = g(x)$, where $x\geq1$ , which is obtained by rotating the graph of  $y = f (x)$ through $180°$ about the point $(1, –1)$.

---

So for this question I don't really understand the wording , what does it mean by rotating the graph $y=f(x)$ through $180°$ about the point $(1,-1)$?

The only progress I made on this question was to find a point of inflection of $f(x)$ which is

$$f'(x)=3x^2-6x-1 \Leftrightarrow f''(x)=6x-6=0 \Leftrightarrow ~\therefore x=1$$

But I am not sure what to do with that...

Comment: Hint: Think it terms of transformations of functions. You want to rotate about a point that isn't the origin. This is the same as taking the translation that moves the desired center of rotation to the origin, rotating as desired, and then translating the rotation point back to where it originally was. (This is an example of conjugation in the group of transformations of the plane).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general answer:  rotation of the graph of a function $f$ around  a point $(a,b)$ is but the symmetry of the graph w.r.t. this point, hence it is
$$y=g(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}2b-f(2a-x).$$

To see this, denote $x,y=f(x)$ a point on the original graph, and $(X,Y=g(X)$ athe symmetric point. By definition, we have
$X=2a-x$, $Y=2b-y$ (writing the point $(a,b)$ is the middle point of $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$).

Comment: Could you explain how you dervied that?

Comment: I've added some details. The only thing to know is the equation(s) of a symmetry.

Comment: What are the equations of symmetry (I have never come across them during my highschool)

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the function is shown below:
[image]

It is clear that if we rotate the part $\{(x,f(x)):x \geq 1\}$ we get the portion of the graph $\{(x,f(x)): x \leq 1\}$. Hence $g = f$. This can also be seen as follows: If we rotate the point $P(x,f(x))$ on the curve by $180^\circ$ about $(1,-1)$, then we obtain the point $(2-x, -2-f(x))$. Note that $f(2-x)+f(x) = -2$ and hence $f(2-x) = - 2 - f(x)$ and $g= f$.